# Group by with linked conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have this table

```
CompanyCode|Year|Personcode
1234       |2019|1
1234       |2019|2
1234       |2020|1
1234       |2020|2
2222       |2020|1
2222       |2020|2
```

Now I want to check what companies have entries for 2019 and 2020. My idea was:

```
Select companycode from table
where year = '2019' and year = '2020'
group by compnaycode
```

But the result is empty. Could anyone tell my how to do this query?

Comment: Can't you just select distinct company codes where year in (2019,2020)

Comment: The result was empty, because the year cannot be both `2019` and `2020` on the same row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering you only want the value of `CompanyCode`, I would personally use a `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT CompanyCode
FROM dbo.YourTable
GROUP CompanyCode
HAVING COUNT(CASE [Year] WHEN 2019 THEN 1 END) >= 1
   AND COUNT(CASE [Year] WHEN 2020 THEN 1 END) >= 1;
```

`[Year]` would never be able to have both the values `2019` **and** `2020` at the *same time*, and hence why your attempt failed.

Answer (score 2):

You can do aggregation :

```
select CompanyCode
from table t
where [year] in (2019, 2020)
group by CompanyCode
having count(distinct [year]) = 2;
```